# rewrite 2 php variables clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website.co.uk/product.php?id=123456&name=name-of-product

and would like to rewrite this to:

```
website.co.uk/product/123456/name-of-product
```

or even better:

```
website.co.uk/123456/name-of-product
```

I have this which rewrites the first variable $id

```
RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/?$    product.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

to product/123456

just need the second variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another rule for the 2 parameter URI:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: this works thanks - is it possible to remove the product/ so that it would just show 123456/name-of-product?

Comment: Sure last rule can become: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: since changing the htaccess file, I notice that if I am on a product page and click a link eg 'home.php' it places product/123456/name-of-product/home.php before the link which breaks it... should I change all my links to http://www.website.co.uk/home.php instead of just 'home.php' and the same for all other pages? - It all works if I do this but just seeing if there is an easier way rather than changing all internal links to have website.co.uk/ in front of them

Comment: Or you can just place a `/` before `home.php` like `<a href="/home.php">Home</a>`

Comment: Or else you can try using `BASE` tag like this: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thanks 1 last problem, the name variable sometimes contains special characters eg , ' * . and numbers - can you tell me what else is needed in the rewrite to allow these links to work?  thanks

Comment: Just change rule to: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Simply match another variable (correct the range to suit your needs):

```
RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$    product.php?id=$1&name=$2    [NC,L]
```

When in doubt working with regular expressions, I highly recommend [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/), great small software for experimenting and testing your expressions.